# Video.module: Rendering playablefiles programmatically

Tags: entities, files

I am trying to pull the "playablefiles" URIs from the array for a video field (hereafter: field_video).

[Here's a look](http://pastebin.com/0BYHJpAL) at how the array is set up.

I'm trying to pull a list of the files by this method, which seems to be in error:

```
  foreach($node->field_video['und']['0']['playablefiles']) {
    echo $node->field_video['und']['0']['playablefiles']['uri'];
  }
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that could do with attention...

- A [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) statement needs an `as` keyword to keep a reference to the current object in the iteration (the docs explain it better than that, it's worth having a read). This error should throw an exception.
- From the looks of the array each 'playablefile' is an object (not an array) so you need to access its members with `->` not `[]`. If the interpreter makes it this far this should also throw an exception.
- You can also make use of the API and make your code language safe using the [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) function

The resulting code should be:

```
$field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_video');
foreach ($field_items[0]['playablefiles'] as $file) {
  echo $file->uri;
}
```